# Phaser resizeWorld() undefined

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'resizeWorld' of undefined
>       at Game.Level1.create (Level1.js:16)
>       at i.StateManager.loadComplete (phaser.min.js:3)
>       at i.StateManager.preUpdate (phaser.min.js:3)
>       at i.Game.updateLogic (phaser.min.js:3)
>       at i.Game.update (phaser.min.js:3)
>       at i.RequestAnimationFrame.updateRAF (phaser.min.js:3)
>       at window.requestAnimationFrame.forceSetTimeOut._onLoop (phaser.min.js:3)

Code:

```
        var player;
        var controls = {};
        var playerSpeed = 40;


        Game.Level1.prototype={
            create:function(){


                this.map=this.game.add.tilemap('map1');
                this.map.addTilesetImage('tileSet','tiles');
                this.layer = this.map.createLayer('floor');
                this.layer.resizeWorld();




                this.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
                player = this.add.sprite(200,200,'player');
                player.anchor.setTo(0.5,0.5);

                player.animations.add('up',[9,10,11,],5,true);
                player.animations.add('down',[0,1,2],5,true);
                player.animations.add('right',[3,4,5],5,true);
                player.animations.add('left',[6,7,8],5,true);
                this.physics.enable(player, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

                this.camera.follow(player);


                controls = {
                    right: this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.A),
                    left: this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.D),
                    up: this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.W),
                    down: this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.S),

                };

            },

            update:function(){
                this.physics.arcade.collide(player,layer);
                player.body.velocity.y =0;
                player.body.velocity.x=0;
                if(controls.up.isDown){
                    player.animations.play('up');

                    player.body.velocity.y -= playerSpeed;
                }
                if(controls.down.isDown){
                    player.animations.play('down');

                    player.body.velocity.y += playerSpeed;
                }
                if(controls.right.isDown){
                    player.animations.play('right');

                    player.body.velocity.x -= playerSpeed;
                }
                if(controls.left.isDown){
                    player.animations.play('left');

                    player.body.velocity.x += playerSpeed;
                }


            },
        }*
```

Comment: Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: I don't know phaser, but from the error it looks like this.layer is undefined. and if so, the this.map.createLayer('floor') returns undefined.

Comment: logically it means you are trying to access something which is not defined. check what is your this.layer

Comment: I have tried many ways but its still undefined.

Comment: Have you verified that your layer is actually called `floor` in Tiled? Are you getting any other console or network errors?

Comment: Thanks, it's not phaser's problem. I used tilemap editor to create json map file, and i set zilb compression on. but phaser only recognize none zilb compression json file

Answer (score 0):

I have an example in my project Zelda Mysteries of Phaser CE that works like this

```
var game;
var map;
var layer1, layer2, layer3;
var player;
var cursors;

game = new Phaser.Game(640, 480, Phaser.CANVAS, 'Zelda Mysteries of Phaser CE', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update, render: render });

function preload() {

    game.load.tilemap('hyrule', 'assets/tiles/hyrule.json', null, Phaser.Tilemap.TILED_JSON);
    game.load.image('light_world', 'assets/tiles/light_world.tiles.png');
    game.load.spritesheet('link', 'assets/sprites/walking.tunic.png', 24, 32, 55);
}

function create() {
    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
//World
    map = game.add.tilemap('hyrule');
    map.addTilesetImage('light_world.tiles', 'light_world');


// Order of layer in tile editor is important for collision
    layer1 = map.createLayer('Calque de Tile 1');
    layer2 = map.createLayer('Calque 2');

    layer1.resizeWorld();

//The big tree i didn't uses a collision for the little trees yet
    map.setCollisionBetween(1078, 1085, true, layer2);//look at the id in tiled on the spritesheet
    map.setCollisionBetween(1174, 1181, true, layer2);
    map.setCollisionBetween(1271, 1276, true, layer2);
    map.setCollisionBetween(1369, 1370, true, layer2);

    game.world.setBounds(0, 0, 1280, 960);

//Player
    player = game.add.sprite(50, 150, 'link');
    //player.scale.set(2);
    player.smoothed = false;

//As the order of the layers is important it's also important here
//to call it after the sprite
    layer3 = map.createLayer('Calque 3');

    player.animations.add('right', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 16, false);
    player.animations.add('up', [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18], 16, false);
    player.animations.add('left', [33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40], 16, false);
    player.animations.add('down', [44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51], 16, false);

    game.physics.enable(player);
    game.camera.follow(player);

    cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

}

function update() {
    game.physics.arcade.collide(player, layer2);
    player.body.collideWorldBounds = true;

    player.body.velocity.x = 0;
    player.body.velocity.y = 0;

    var speed = 160;

    if (cursors.right.isDown)
    {
        game.camera.x += 4;
        player.body.velocity.x = +speed;
        player.animations.play('right');
    }

    else if (cursors.up.isDown)
    {
        game.camera.y -= 4;
        player.body.velocity.y = -speed;
        player.animations.play('up');
    }

    else if (cursors.left.isDown)
    {
        game.camera.x -= 4;
        player.body.velocity.x = -speed;
        player.animations.play('left');
    }

    else if (cursors.down.isDown)
    {
        game.camera.y += 4;
        player.body.velocity.y = +speed;
        player.animations.play('down');
    } else {

        player.animations.stop();
    }

}

function render() {

    game.debug.spriteInfo(player, 20, 32);

}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's not phaser's problem. I used tilemap editor to create json map file, and i set zilb compression on. but phaser only recognize none zilb compression json file.

Comment: I don't really know for what is used zlib but if it can be implemented in Phaser 2 CE why not openning an issue for that as an enhancement, happy it works for you know

Answer (score 0):

If you are using phase 3, try below:

```
this.physics.world.setBounds(0, 0, layer.width, layer.height);
```

if you debug into phase 2 lib, you will find the function `setBounds` is called, but in P3 its been upgraded under `physics.world`.